# Assumptions of additive model

Tags: regression, nonparametric, assumptions, generalized-additive-model

An additive model takes the form:
$y=\alpha+f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+...+f_p(x_p)+\epsilon$

If I've understood correctly, there are only two assumption on the errors:
- errors have mean zero
- errors are homoschedastic

Since an additive model is a generalization of the linear model, are $Y|X$ supposed to be normal too? Are errors supposed to be uncorrelated as in the linear model?

Thank you.

Comment: this depends on the context. additive noise can be anything...

Answer (score 1):

There's only a requirement of normality if, say

(a) you want least squares to be optimal (in the sense of say achieving a Cramer-Rao lower bound); or

(b) you want to apply a test or construct an interval that assumes it. (For example, if you want to get a prediction interval, you might try to assume it then.)

Conversely, if your data are highly non-normal, your estimates will be inefficient (as would any linear estimator), and in that case you generally wouldn't want to try to base tests or intervals off a normality assumption.

Answer (score 0):

@Glen_b's answer is good to review to correct the premise of your question.

Specifically concerning $Y|X$, by which I presume you mean the conditional mean: no there are no requirements about the "distribution" of the $\hat{Y}$ or consequently the $X$. These are considered fixed in OLS, hence do not follow a distribution. It is no different for AMs.

The errors should be uncorrelated, also similar.