# Why is additivity assumption in additive models unrealistic? Is it more unrealistic than the assumption of Linearity?

Tags: regression, assumptions, generalized-additive-model

I have gone through the following questions regarding the assumptions of additive models.

[Assumptions of additive model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167730/assumptions-of-additive-model)

[What does the additive assumption mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260175/what-does-the-additive-assumption-mean)

However, I do not quite get the intuitive understanding of why additive assumptions are regarded as unrealistic. 
And how unrealistic is it? (if it's quantifiable) 
Is it more unrealistic than the assumption of Linearity ?

Can anybody please demonstrate with a simple real-world example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose our inputs are $x\in\mathbb R^p$ and we are trying to model $y\in\mathbb R$ using a function $f : \mathbb R^p\to\mathbb R$.

An additive model is of the form
$$
f(x) = \beta_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m\beta_ih_i(x_i)
$$
so we're saying that $f$, our potentially complicated function of a $p$-dimensional input, is built out of functions only of each coordinate separately.

Note that if $h_i(x_i) = x_i$ then this reduces to a standard linear model, so additive models generalize linear models.

This is restrictive because we're missing so many possible functions, like if $y = x_1x_2$ we won't be able to exactly capture that. Any function that needs to simultaneously consider multiple coordinates of $x$ at once won't be exactly model-able with an additive function.

Another way to see why this is so restrictive is that once we fix our basis functions $\{h_1,\dots,h_m\}$ we are only considering functions in the span of this set, and that'll be at most an $m$-dimensional subspace of the probably infinite dimension function space that could contain the "true" function, so in that sense we have almost no chance of the true function being in our thin slice through this space that we're considering.

Comment: This assumes a very narrow view of functions $f$; there is nothing stopping us having a function $f(x_1,x_2)$ and estimating that function via a tensor product of the marginal bases for $x_1$ and $x_2$ say. The issue of basis dimension is problematic, but i) advice is to set the dimensionality sufficiently large to include the expected wiggliness/true function, and ii) we could make do with an approximation to the true function.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-G.Simpson I was thinking about when the true function would exactly be in the class of functions we are considering or not, that isn't helped by things like tensor products of marginal bases right? It'd be a good way to estimate a nonadditive function with an additive one but the true function still wouldn't be in our class of additive functions right?

Comment: –1 You write "…if $y=x_1x_2$ we won't be able to exactly capture that." But this is hogwash in additive models like multiple regressions where multiplicative interaction terms such as $x_1x_2$ are both trivially easy and commonplace to **add** to other right-hand terms.

Comment: @Alexis I don't think I understand your point. Sure we can approximate interactions with additive functions but a nonadditive function won't actually be in the function space in question so function-wise we're inconsistent at best

Comment: Variable $x_3 = x_1x_2$, now I can, for example: $y = \beta_3x_3 +\epsilon$, or $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 +\beta_3x_3 +\epsilon$, or $y = f_1(x_1,\theta_1) + f_2(x_2,\theta_2) +f_3(x_3,\theta_3) + \epsilon$, etc. Those are all additive models perfectly able to capture $x_1x_2$ in a variety of ways.

Comment: @Alexis sure that's additive in $(x_1, x_2, x_1x_2)$ but it's still not additive in the original variables which is what I'm talking about. I'm talking about what it means for a function to be additive, not if a non-additive function can be represented by an additive function if we change the domain. That's obviously also true but I think that's a separate point

Comment: How is that separate in any linear modeling context?

Comment: @Alexis I think we're having the same discussion as whether or not $y = x_1 + x_1^2 + \varepsilon$ is a "linear model" and you're saying it is because it's linear in the parameters and I'm saying it's not a linear function of $x_1$ and we're both right.

Comment: It is also an additive model.